# Why is Apache Flink droping the event from datastream?

Tags: java, junit, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In the following unit test case, some event specified by **numberOfElements** is generated and fed as a data stream. This unit cases randomly fails at the line.

> assertEquals(numberOfElements, CollectSink.values.size());

Any explanation why Apache Flink is skipping the events.

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class FlinkTest {

StreamExecutionEnvironment env;

@Before
public void setup() {
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
}

@Test
public void testStream1() throws Exception {
    testStream();
}

@Test
public void testStream2() throws Exception {
    testStream();
}

@Test
public void testStream3() throws Exception {
    testStream();
}

@Test
public void testStream4() throws Exception {
    testStream();
}


@Test
public void testStream() throws Exception {

    final int numberOfElements = 50;

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> tupleStream = env.fromCollection(getCollectionOfBucketImps(numberOfElements));
    CollectSink.values.clear();
    tupleStream.addSink(new CollectSink());
    env.execute();
    sleep(2000);

    assertEquals(numberOfElements, getCollectionOfBucketImps(numberOfElements).size());
    assertEquals(numberOfElements, CollectSink.values.size());
}


public static List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> getCollectionOfBucketImps(int numberOfElements) throws InterruptedException {
    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> records = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        records.add(new Tuple2<>(Integer.toString(i % 10), i));
    }
    return records;
}

// create a testing sink
private static class CollectSink implements SinkFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    public static final List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> values = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void invoke(Tuple2<String, Integer> value, Context context) throws Exception {
        values.add(value);
    }
 }
}
```

For examples either of testStreamX case fails randomly.

Context: The code runs with 8 as parallelism setu since the cpu where it runs has 8 Cores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the paralellism of your jobs (i suppose that is the max that Flink can assign). Looks like you can have a Race condition on the add value of your sink.

**Solution**

I have runned your example code, setting the environment parallelism to 1 and everything works fine. The documentation examples about testing uses this solution [link to documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/testing.html).

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(1);
}
```

**Even Better**

You can set the parallelism to 1 only on the sink operator and mantain the parallelism of the rest of the pipeline. In the following example, i added an extra map function with a forced parallelism of 8 for tha map operator.

```
public void testStream() throws Exception {

    final int numberOfElements = 50;

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> tupleStream = env.fromCollection(getCollectionOfBucketImps(numberOfElements));
    CollectSink.values.clear();
    tupleStream
            .map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<String,Integer>, Tuple2<String,Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<String,Integer> map(Tuple2<String, Integer> stringIntegerTuple2) throws Exception {

                    stringIntegerTuple2.f0 += "- concat something";

                    return stringIntegerTuple2;
                }
            }).setParallelism(8)
            .addSink(new CollectSink()).setParallelism(1);
    env.execute();
    sleep(2000);

    assertEquals(numberOfElements, getCollectionOfBucketImps(numberOfElements).size());
    assertEquals(numberOfElements, CollectSink.values.size());
}
```

Comment: I tried using synchronized method @diegoreico . It didn't help. I elaborated the code so that it can be reproduced easily.  FYI `default void invoke(IN value)` is deprecated in 1.4 so the document need be updated also.

Comment: i have updated the answer with a working solution for the code that you have provided :) and you should send a mail to Flink's dev mailing list talking about the deprecation of the invoke function dev@flink.apache.org

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution 2 works but solution 1 didn't. When I ran it several times, randomly it fails. However the frequency of failure cases has significantly went down. One in 100 types but not 0. In other words, when there is single stream it works (like solution 2) but in my machine ( which has 8 core) creates 8 parallel stream then solution 1 didn't worked. Is there any bug in Flink stream reader? I tried to did more debugging and seems like problem is number of records being read from circular buffer.

Comment: I gave +1 as the solution 2 works for specific case ( single stream) but still looking for solution which works with several stream. Providing more context in the question.

Comment: i think that i have a solution for multiple streams, check it if you can.

Comment: Yes, it works. Tested with 10000 runs.  I would close the question with remark that `public synchronized void invoke` didn't worked as specified. Further investigation does not fall under the scope of this question and could be taken further by Flink team. Thanks @diegoreico for quick support.

Answer (score 2):

When a paralellism of the environment is greater than 1, there are multiple instances of `CollectSink`, which is possible to cause a race condition.

These are solutions to avoid the race condition:

1. Synchronize on class object

```java
private static class CollectSink implements SinkFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    public static final List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> values = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void invoke(Tuple2<String, Integer> value, Context context) throws Exception {
        synchronized(CollectSink.class) {
            values.add(value);
        }
    }
 }
```

2. `Collections.synchronizedList()`

```java
import java.util.Collections;
private static class CollectSink implements SinkFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    public static final List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> values = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    @Override
    public void invoke(Tuple2<String, Integer> value, Context context) throws Exception {
        values.add(value);
    }
 }
```